# Error on auth and cors using Spring Boot, Spring Security and Vue.js with axios

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

I am running vue.js 3, with Vite 4.0.2, axios 0.25.0 and spring boot (Starter 2.7.2).

I've created a backend in spring boot, while using vue.js3, vite and axios as UI.
Now, i simply wanted to call to rest with axios.
Right before i implemented these functions i tested the rest api with postman and intelliJ http-request. All of them were successfull.

Following setup is running:
Spring boot app: http://localhost:9050
Vue.js3: http://127.0.0.1:517x (where x is something between 1-4).

In Order to get this running, i checked here at stackoverflow a lot of answers, but none of them brought solution to this, neither a lot of research in general.

Here's the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("userPass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build());

        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("adminPass"))
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        final CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(r -> corsConfiguration)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE)
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .anonymous()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

on the other side, in vue. Note: i added allow-origin with * just to get this working, i've planned later on a more restrictive declaration.

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api/v1/products/all': {
                target: 'http://localhost:9050/',
                ws: true,
                changeOrigin: true,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Type', // hier hostname:port statt * , Origin, Content-Type, Authorization
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // hier hostname:port statt *
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
                    Authorization: 'Basic admin adminPass'
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

and finally a script in vue:

```
    const {data, status} = await axios.get<GetProductPojoResponse>(
        'http://localhost:9050/api/v1/products/all',
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Type', // hier hostname:port statt * ', Origin, Content-Type, Authorization'
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // hier hostname:port statt *
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            Authorization: 'Basic admin adminPass',
            withCredentials: true,
          },
        },
    );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

    // ?? "response status is: 200"
    console.log('response status is: ', status);

    return data;
```

I've managed to get CORS errors in combination with error 401 and 403, but i can't explain why.....

Comment: I am fairly sure that Authorization: 'Basic admin adminPass' will cause a 401. It needs to be ‘Basic ‘ + Base64(‘admin:adminPass’)

Answer (score 0):

Cors error usually comes from the backend. It seems like you aren't specifying which links you want to give access to your backend. In your filterChain() method, the corsConfiguration, add something like
corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("vueJsSiteLinkHereGoesHere"));

This is the security config I used for my angular project. Note that I did not implement WebMvcConfigurer.

Also, make sure you don't have @CrossOrigins annotation on your controller class because it will override what is set here.

I'm using jwt for authentication so you might need to add/remove some headers to suit your needs

```
package com.example.backend.security;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.List;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity()
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final AppProperties appProps;
    private static final String[] WHITELISTED_URLS = {
            "/auth/**",
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults()) // by default, use a bean of the name corsConfigurationSource
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) // not really needed in REST
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2/**")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(WHITELISTED_URLS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(appProps.getFrontendSite()));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false); // we're using jwt
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

See this video by Dan Vega on youtube. He also has some stuff on vue: https://youtu.be/HRwlT_etr60

Comment: hi, there, i tried to disable cors in firefox:
) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf http://localhost:9050/api/v1/products/all. (Grund: CORS deaktiviert).


and later:

e auf http://localhost:9050/api/v1/products/all. (Grund: Kopfzeile 'access-control-allow-headers' ist aufgrund der Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' aus der CORS-Preflight-Antwort nicht zulässig).

it's driving me crazy.....

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are multiple ways for resolve this:

in Backend:
corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));

Which is the worst....

The second, "workaround"-style is to copy the dist-files into target folder and make a configuration forwarding to index.html.

It's really crazy, sending rest-requests in a non-browser environment were always successfull, without x-site errors.....